# Do I need to host my receiver app on my own server?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

When I register a Chromecast receiver app, it asks for a URL. Is that where the receiver html file is?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to use one of our receivers (Styled or Default), in which case you do not need to register any URL or you need to use your own custom receiver which requires you to arrange for its hosting. See tour [docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps).

Comment: Ok. Do you know where I can learn more about hosting the receiver app? I'm guessing it might be different than hosting a regular html file/website, since a normal computer shouldn't be allowed to access it, like they would a website.

Comment: It is like any other hosting, no difference; you need to make sure that your page can be accessed over SSL (issued by a known authority, i.e. no self-signed certs allowed). Any client, including a desktop browser, can access your page. During development (i.e. prior to publishing your app), you can use http. AppEngine is one production hosting option since it has valid certs. You can even use Google Drive (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en), although that is not recommended for production.